# How to set page break based on the result of our tablix in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have three tablix in designer window.My first tablix always gives some data.Do do not put condtion to that tablix.Given a page brreak at the end of that tablix.
I need below mentioned requirement.
1.If all three tablix contains data then need page break in every tablix.
2.If only tablix1 and tablix 2 has data then it should do a page break only after the tablix1.
3.When only tablix1 and tablix3 data has present then only add a page break between this two only.

Please give some suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Ssrs are you using?

Comment: http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/b414a0978a60/ssrs-wrap-line-break-row-objects-within-group.html